# appendTo (); jquery add div after the button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I'm cloning div and adding it at the end ( `appendTo();` ) I want the duplicated div to append right after the button click. As of now it is adding the divs at the end.

Any solution ?

My fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/kgm50e43/15/

Comment: Your code is working. What do you need? That question is meritory to be closed if you don't edit and explain your problem and what you need understanding all humans.

Comment: What is your expected output? If you can be more clear someone can help you.

Comment: right now at button click it adds at the end of div. which ever button clicked. 
I want which ever button clicked 2,3 or any it should add after it  and not at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what `.appendTo` method does. You can use the `.insertAfter` method instead:

```
// cache the target element
var $parent = $(this).closest(".clonedInput");
// clone the target element 
// and insert the cloned object after the target element 
$parent.clone().insertAfter($parent);
```

Note that I have used the `closest` method instead of the `parents` method  as you just want to select the first/closest matching parent element. `parents` is a greedy method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the methods `.after()` `.insertAfter()`. Please check snippet below.

```js
//Clone js
var count = 1;
function clone(){
  if (count < 5) {
    var newOne = $(this).closest(".clonedInput").clone(true);
    newOne.find('button.clone').css({'background':'#'+Math.random().toString(16).slice(-6)});
    //background just to show where it landed
    newOne.insertAfter($(this).closest(".clonedInput"));
    count++;
  } 
}
$(".Counter_Play").on("click", 'button.clone', clone);
```

```css
.al_icons,.clonedInput,.main_icoset{position:relative;overflow:hidden}.clone{display:block;background-color:red;padding:10px}.clonedInput{margin-top:30px;background:#f5f5f5}.IconTest{background:green;width:100px;height:30px;text-align:center;margin-bottom:20px}.main_icoset{width:100%;height:30px}.al_icons{width:34px;height:20px;background-color:#263238;color:#fff;font-size:7px;line-height:22px;text-align:center;float:left;margin-right:2px;display:none;margin-top:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
show hide icons from selected dropdown within the same div. 
<div class="Counter_Play">
  <div class="col s12 l12 m12 First_sec clonedInput">
    Attach only aftter this if this button pressed
    <div class="col s2 m2 l2">
      <button class="clone btn-floating btn-small waves-effect waves-light red counter_start_btn" >
        <i class="material-icons">Duplicate</i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is use .insertAfter instead of appendTo, though there are several issues with the fiddle you provided.

The most notable issue is that you have registered duplicate actions on click. Both in your html and in JS.

```
<button class="clone btn-floating btn-small waves-effect waves-light red counter_start_btn" onclick="clone();">
```

and

```
$("button.clone").on("click", clone);
```

Feel free to study my revision of the most critical points:

http://jsfiddle.net/thomasmars/kgm50e43/17/